# Rails: App displays table/model name instead of data from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm very new to rails and putting together my first app. Please bear with me!

I'm making an app that lets the user rate the video games they are playing. On the site I've made a page where the user can see a list of all the games that he/she has rated in the past.

I'm running into some issues and I think it's pretty simple but it's driving me crazy.

In the controller I have:

```
def index
  @rate = Rate.where(:rater_id => current_user.id)

  @ratename = Game.where(:id => @rate.first.rateable_id)

  end
```

And in my view I have:

```
  <% @rates.order("created_at desc").each do |rates| %>

      You are playing <%= @ratename.name %></div>

  <% end %>
```

Where I'm confused is that in the browser this is displayed: "You are playing Game"

How do I get it to display the name of the game not just "Game"?

UPATE:

Model for rate:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rateable_id, :rater_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game

end
```

Comment: where() returns a Relationship object (a scope)

Comment: Calling .first on a scope will returns the first object of that scope. Rails Active Record Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: You're aware, that in your controller you defined `@rate` but in your view you access `@rates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referring to the associations directly.

**Controller:**

```
def index
  @rates = current_user.rates.order("created_at desc")
end
```

**View:**

```
<% @rates.each do |rate| %>
  You are playing <%= rate.game.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Results in "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass". Rate doesn't have a name column. What I'm trying to do is display the name of the Game whose id matches the Rate's "rateable_id".

Comment: Thank you, there ended up being another issue elsewhere but this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ratename = Game.where(:id => @rate.first.rateable_id)
```

means that you find Game with all attributes, not only name.

The right way:

in controller:

```
@rates = current_user.rates.order("created_at desc") #will work if you made correct associations (user has many rates)
```

in view:

```
<% @rates each do |rate| %>   
  You are playing <%= rate.game.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

rate.game.name will work if you made correct associations: game has many rates, rate belongs to game.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion just do this

in index

```
def index
   @rates = current_user.rates.includes(:game).order("created_at desc")
end


in view

     <% @rates.each do |rate| %>

      You are playing <%= rate.game.name %></div>

  <% end %>
```

this will solve your problem plus it will improve your server efficiency